# Teclado Virtual en React con Internet Explorer 11

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm

Necesito implementar un teclado virtual cuando se le click a una caja de texto y este se me active, las tecnologias que estoy usando son React, la opcion que tengo hasta ahora solo me lo hace para chrome pero necesito que tambien funcione en IE11 y no se como hacerle no encuentro otras alternativas.
De antemano muchas gracias.
Adjunto errorer que me muestra en el IE11[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando react-app-polyfill?

Comment: si por supuesto pero nada funciona

Comment: Puedes escribir la parte del código donde el error aparece? Y la `browserslist` si la tienes